# wxWidgets can't receive Right mouse click

Tags: windows, contextmenu, wxwidgets

I'm trying to add a context menu to a grid control in wxWidgets 2.9.4 on Windows 10, and while I can get the context menu key to work right clicking doesn't.  Right now I have the following in the header

```
void handle_contextMenu(wxContextMenuEvent& event);
void handle_rightButton(wxMouseEvent& event);
```

and in the constructor

```
Bind(wxEVT_CONTEXT_MENU, &DataGrid::handle_contextMenu, this);
Bind(wxEVT_RIGHT_UP, &DataGrid::handle_rightButton, this);
```

neither work for the right mouse button.

Comment: what type is DataGrid? And why do you want 2 handlers?

Comment: DataGrid is wxGrid, and I don't actually want 2 handlers, I just want one that works.  I've tried both individually, but while the context menu key on the keyboard will work for the first one, the right mouse button doesn't work for either.

Comment: according to https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_event.html, you need wxEVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK.

Comment: @Igor, thanks that was it.  I was looking at generic event handling not realizing that wxGrid had its own events.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't bind to these events on `wxGrid` itself is that it's a composite window as explained in the "Accessors for component windows" section of [the documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html). So to make this code work you need to call `GetGridWindow()->Bind(...)`, for example.

Alternatively, you could, and probably should, if they're enough, use the higher level events such as the already mentioned `wxEVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK`.